# Для чего нужны транзакции в базе данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, linq2db

Использую надстройку для ADO linq2db. Там есть методы, BeginTransaction, RollbackTransaction, CommitTransaction. В моём приложении использую стандартные методы для работы с бд, такие как Insert, Update, Delete, Select. Пытался искать по документации, но ничего толкого, а тем более с примерами найти не смог. Про сами транзакции пишут, что они повышают производительность и т д. Но как их использовать допустим для добавления записи в бд не знаю...

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, транзакции нужны для логической группировки (unit of work) и изоляции: чтобы можно было отменить начатую операцию, даже если половину данных уже как бы изменена, и чтобы пока изменения не завершатся, другие не видели «наполовину изменённые» данные

Comment: непонятно, что вы искали и что не нашли. Ваш вопрос по транзацияи в общем или по вашей БД в частности?

Comment: что гугл про транзации гоаорит, читали? [Для чего нужны транзакции в базе данных](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: [Транза́кция (англ. transaction)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) — группа последовательных операций с базой данных, которая представляет собой логическую единицу работы с данными. Транзакция может быть выполнена либо целиком и успешно, соблюдая целостность данных и независимо от параллельно идущих других транзакций, либо не выполнена вообще, и тогда она не должна произвести никакого эффекта.

Comment: То что гугл говорит я читал. Мне не понятны транзакции по отношению к linq2db. Даже скажу по другому, в какой ситуации мне может понадобится использование транзакций.

Comment: Чтобы распараллелить вставку есть asyncinsert. Чтобы загрузить большой объём данных, есть BulkCopy. У меня в бд используются простейшие операции. Но мне хотелось бы разобраться с этими самыми транзакциями. Может быть благодаря именно транзакциям я смогу решить какие то трудноразрешимые вопросы.

Comment: Транзакции в linq2db делают то же самое, что в любом другом способе работы с БД. будь то EF, Dapper, чистый ADO.NET.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Повышение производительности, это одно и далеко не самое главное, применение транзакций.

Обычно, когда говорят о использовании транзакций для производительности, то имеется ввиду, что можно сэкономить на накладных расходах делая больше операций в одной транзакции. При выполнении транзакции всегда есть накладные расходы и дорогостоящие операции. Самое главное, что фиксация транзакции (commit), всегда требует записи на диск и ожидания, что запись произошла. Даже если вы выполняете простую операцию, типа `Update` и явно не управляете транзакцией, она все равно будет создана неявно и вы несете эти накладные расходы.

Выполнение нескольких операций в одной транзакции может существенно повысить производительность, особенно если операции сами по себе очень маленькие, а значит накладные расходы относительно большие.

Но как я уже написал, использование транзакций для улучшения производительности далеко не самая главная причина. Более важно это то, что транзакции дают возможность поддерживать атомарность и изоляцию операций а также целостность данных. Приведу несколько простых типичных примеров, когда использование транзакций существенно упрощает жизнь.

### Пример 1

Типичный пример, когда нужно сделать два модифицирующих запроса. И важно, чтоб они оба были выполнены (или ни один не был). Перевод денег с одного счета на другой.

```
Операция 1: уменьшить значение счета A на 100 USD.
Операция 2: увеличить значение счета B на 100 USD.
```

Допустим не используются транзакции. Если произойдет проблема после того, как выполнилась первая операция, но не выполнилась вторая, то у нас пропало 100 USD. И очень нетривиально такую проблему разрулить.

Варианты типа, `просто вернуть эти 100 USD на счет А` сталкиваются с проблемой, что очень непросто сделать так, чтоб информация о том, что нужно сделать этот возврат не потерялась, т.к. проблема из-за которой это случилось может быть в том, что сервер на котором выполнялся этот код просто вышел из строя (сгорел, например) и у нас нет информации о том, что он успел сделать в рамках этой транзакции. Логи тоже могли пропасть и мы даже не будем знать, что у нас выполнялись какие-то операции, когда сервер вышел из строя.

Так же может быть проблема на стороне самой БД, например, БД недоступна вообще по сети - сгорела сетевая карта на сервере БД или закончилось место на диске, где  БД хранит данные. И вернуть деньги назад, что означает сделать запрос в БД, который добавит к A 100 USD, просто невозможно.

И что если во время выполнения кода компенсирующего операцию 1 произойдет сбой? Надеюсь идея понятна: в абсолютно любом месте программы может произойти программный или аппаратный сбой. При этом возникает куча нетривиальных проблем.

Использование же транзакции тут простой способ полностью избежать данной проблемы. Транзакция (т.е. эти две операции) либо полностью пройдет успешно, либо (если сервер упадет после первой операции) вообще не пройдет. Во втором случае, БД автоматически отменит первую операцию и эти 100 USD никуда не пропадут.

### Пример 2

Программа может генерировать отчет и для этого делать несколько запросов в БД. Например, на одной странице excel файла показан баланс по текущим счетам пользователей, а на другой баланс по депозитным счетам тех же пользователей. И представим, что это делается двумя запросами (это не невероятное предположение, обычно запросы такого типа довольно сложные,  в них куча логики и делать это одним большим запросом часто сложно с точки зрения как производительности так и поддержки кода этого запроса).

На большой базе каждый такой запрос может занимать продолжительное время. Теперь, если мы не используем транзакции, то есть проблема с тем, что каждый из запросов видит состояние базы данных в разные моменты времени. И например может быть так, что между этими двумя запросами могут вклиниться другие операции, которые выполняются с этими же счетами. Например, какой-то клиент, может открыть новый депозитный счет и перевести деньги на него с текущего счета.

Если последовательность действий была такая:

```
Время     | Операции генерации отчета    |       Операция открытия депозита
----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------
t1        |  получить часть отчета       |  
          |  для текущих счетов запросом |
          |  в БД                        |
----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------
t2        |                              | перевести 100 USD с текущего счета 
          |                              | клиента A на депозитный
----------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------
t3        |  получить часть отчета       |  
          |  для депозитных счетов       |
          |  запросом в БД               |
```

Получится, что одни и те же 100 USD будут два раза включены в отчет для клиента A и будет выглядеть, что у него 200 USD, хотя на самом деле только 100.

Используя транзакцию при генерации отчета можно сделать так, чтоб все запросы видели состояние БД на определенный момент.