# где правильно использовать аннотацию @Transactional

Tags: java, spring

- есть компонент-1, помеченный @Repository, в котором вызываются методы, возвращающие `return jdbc.query(sqlString, params, new QuestionMapper());`
- есть компонент-2, помеченный @Service, в котором вызываются методы компонента-1 и иногда выполняется доп. обработка полученных данных.

аннотация @Transactional установлена для методов компонента-2 (@Service), но мне кажется, что это неверно. Транзакция нужна только для выполнения запроса к БД, т.е. для методов компонента-1 (@Repository).

Почему все статьи рекомендуют использовать аннотацию @Transactional в компоненте уровня @Service, а не @Repository ?

у меня компонент @Repository содержит только jdbc-обращения к БД.

Comment: Ну а если вы 10 раз будете из сервиса вызывать репозиторий, вам в таком случае одна транзакция нужна или 10?

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно вы не до конца понимаете, что такое транзакция и зачем она нужна.

Транзакция это последовательность операций, которые выполняются как одно целое. То есть либо все выполнятся сразу, либо, если, случится ошибка, не одна не выполнится.

Используется это для того, чтоб высокоуровневые операции (например, пользователь переводит деньги со счета на счет), которые требуют нескольких низкоуровневых операций (читай запросов в БД, с одного счета снять, на другой добавить), не нарушали инвариантов, т.е. не случалось ситуаций, например, что с одного счета деньги сняли, а на другой не добавили, что может случится, например, из-за того, что временно прервалась связь с БД или у сервера БД закончилось место на диске или ваш java процесс просто вышел из-за ошибки в jvm.

Про это очень подробно я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1271227/218971).

Часто бизнес операция требует нескольких запросов в БД. В репозиториях же у вас очень простые и гранулярные методы типа `получить сущность по идентификатору` или `сохранить сущность`. Бизнес операция устанавливает инварианты и таким образом определяет, какие операции нужно выполнить как единое целое, то есть определяет границы транзакции. Так как реализация бизнес операции находится в сервисе, а не в репозитории, то именно метод сервиса мы и аннотируем с помощью `@Transactional`.

Поясню на примере. Рассмотрим реализацию перевода денег со счета на счет, тут код будет приблизительно такой:

```
class AccountService {
@Transactional
public void transfer(Integer fromAccountId, Integer toAccountId, BigDecimal amount) {
  Account fromAccount = accountReporsitory.getById(fromAccountId);
  Account toAccount = accountRegistry.getById(toAccountId);
  if (canTransfer(fromAcount, toAccount, amount)) {
     fromAccount.debit(amount);
     toAccount.credit(amount);
     accountRepository.save(fromAccount);
     accountRepository.save(toAccount);
  } else {
     // ошибка ...
  }
}
}
```

Нам нужно чтоб именно действия в методе `transfer` выполнились как одно целое (все или ничего). Если сделать отдельные транзакции для каждого метода обращения к репозиторию, этого не удасться добиться и будут те проблемы, которые я описал выше.

Comment: у меня логика приложения частично находится в БД. и запросы, аналогичные Вашему примеру, оформлены как процедура БД. Тогда получается, что аннотация @Transactional может находиться в любом компоненте ?

Comment: Возможно да, возможно нет. Приведите в тексте вопроса (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1320224/edit)) код схематично, чтоб было ясно, какой компонент что делает и за что отвечает. В частности из того, что вы написали, выглядит так, что репозиторий не совсем репозиторий (в смысле хранилище объектов без логики). Можно схему кода на этом же упрощенном примере с переводом денег привести.