# Kafka Transaction with IBM MQ transaction

Tags: spring, transaction, apache-kafka

Всем привет. Кейс следующий :

1 Открыть транзакцию Kafka

2 Открыть транзакцию MQ

3 отправить сообщение в топик кафка

4 отправить сообщениу в MQ

5 отправить сообщение в другой топик кафка

6 закрыть транзакцию Кафка

7 закрыть транзакцию МКу

Если происходит ошибка на каком-то шаге, то делаем роллбек

Как это можно осуществить ? Читал про ChainedTransaction но проблема в том что класс Deprecated. Есть какие-то другие варианты? Желательно с примерами.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что на самом деле шаги 1, 2, 6 и 7 вас, как пользователя не интересуют. Вам нужно, чтоб можно было начать и закончить транзакцию  и чтоб шаги 3-5 либо полностью прошли либо нет (+durability). Так?

Comment: Ну вариант с правильной логикой открытия этих транзакций тоже инетерсен. Пытался настраивать вручную, не срабатывает так как нужно. Через аннотации тоже.

Comment: Нет способа добиться транзакционности с двумя ресурсами простым способом как вы описали. Одна из проблем, это откат если случилась проблема после шага 6 из вопроса. Я подробно писал об этом тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1271227/218971 (почитайте пример 1 и подумайте, что он означает для вашего случая). Так же вы упоминаете ChainedTransaction. Он не гарантирует транзакционности и ограничено пригоден в некоторых случаях. Поэтому я и пытаюсь понять чего именно вы хотите достичь, полной транзакционности или все же какие-то компромисы допустимы. Или проблему вообще стоит решать другим способом

Comment: Если еще более короче, то пытаюсь понять эквивалентен ли ваш вопрос такому "Можно ли и если да, то как в спринг сконфигурировать поддержку распределенных транзакций для ibm mq и kafka?"

Comment: Да, на данный момент я это реализовал с помощью спринг аннотаций. При эксепшене в IBM MQ вообще не приходит сообщение, а в кафка топики приходят , но они не помечены как "commited" , но насколько я понял из другого топика - это гуд.